# How to bake texture with same brightness as original?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I try to bake this simple model in cycles render engine.

[image]

but the bake result is always much darker than the original.

How can I bake it so that the result will be an exact copy of the original textures?

[image]

**Render Settings:**

[image]

**World Settings:**

[image]

I learned it from this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aq2tUT0iyCQ

---

Result of Turning Indirect and Direct off (only Color is on)

[image]

Looks washed out.

Comment: cycles or blender internal baking? is your world white? what options did you select in the baking tab?

Comment: I am using Cycles render engine. I will update my post with more infos.

Comment: could you try to disable indirect and direct and bake. It will probably solve your problem

Comment: I tried this already. I will post the result

Comment: also for this case it would be much faster if you switch to blender internal for baking

Comment: But will I loose all the cycles informations then?

Comment: make a backup to make sure you loose nothing but in my experience cycles settings are saved to survive that switch

Comment: also what you could do to make it work in cycles (I guess) is make your would completly white and move all lamps to disabled layers to make sure every part of your mesh will get the same amount of light

Comment: @HenrikD, i think making the world white did the trick :) I also had to reload the baked texture, because it somehow still took the old bake... I will try to reproduce it, then you can make an answer if you like so I can accept it. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out the simplest solution to this problem was to make the world white and disable any lamps to make sure every part of the mesh gets the same amount of light. Blender Internal would be a good alternative but if you're working in cycles you probably don't want to redo all settings after switching back. (Though I do think the setting will stay)

Comment: you mean if you put your light sources on an different layer and bake with only the white world?

Comment: Sorry, It was my fault. Ignore the comment